# Simplifying a fraction with exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need help with simplifying $$\left(\frac{-27}{8}\right)^{{-4}/{3}}$$

This has an exponent as a negative fraction? Does it need to be multiplied?

Comment: You mean to simplify $(-\frac {27}{8})^{-\frac {4}{3}}$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $-27=(-3)^3$ and $8=2^3$, so $(\frac{-27}{8})^{-4/3}=(\frac{-3}{2})^{3(\frac{-4}{3})}=(\frac{-3}{2})^{-4}=(\frac{2}{-3})^4=\frac{16}{81}$, where I used $(\frac{a}{b})^{-n}=(\frac{b}{a})^n$.